# How can I use Selenium in Python to click on a date value in a form?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

can u help me, please? I am trying to click on value 2023-05-25 but this doesn't work

[Choose the date in the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v33oe.png)

```
<form name="applicantBooking2" id="applicantBooking2" action="appointment.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateFrm();">
                <tr id="app_date_tr" height="30">
                    <td width="20%" class="styleBlack" style="padding-left:10px;">
                        Appointment Date: <span style="color:#F00">*</span>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-input app_date validate" style="width: 260px;" id="app_date" name="app_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" onchange="this.form.submit();showLoader();" value="2023-05-25">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

```
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "app_date")))).select_by_visible_text(
                         '2023-05-25')
```

Comment: The tag is marked "readonly".

Comment: So what is the problem?  What does this code **actually do**?

Comment: This code choose the date .I have added a screenshot

Comment: Your script will need to click on the input box, which will open the datepicker. Then it has to click on the date you want. I.e. it has to simulate what you would do with the mouse.

Comment: You'll need to use the Elements panel in DevTools to see how to identify the elements in the datepicker to click on.

Comment: I can't see the output with 'explore' in the browser, only with ctrl+u

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this：

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="form-control-input app_date validate"]').send_key(you_need_date)
```

Because essentially it's just an “input” label.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. It would be great if you can provide the explanation with the answer too, like why would your solution work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#app_date'))).send_keys('2023-05-25')
```

If you notice the `input` tag has `type=text`, so probably you can directly input the value.

And in case this doesn't fix the problem, please add the URL you're using to help you with a better solution.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this.  The third page appointment date - https://armenia.   blsspainvisa.com        /book_appointment.php